# Excluir datos según un rango

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Tengo los siguientes datos en un fichero y me gustaría excluir con `grep` los datos que terminen después del último punto entre 50-100

```
192.168.206.164
192.168.206.183
192.168.90.60
192.168.206.172
192.168.223.9
192.168.216.210
192.168.86.18
```

Es decir, en este caso me deberían de desaparecer:

```
192.168.90.60
```

¿Qué regex debería de usar o qué comando exactamente me lo permitiria?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Además, si hay que excluir de 50 a 100, ¿por qué excluyes .9 y .18 en el ejemplo?

Comment: @Cuauhtli ¿por qué modificas el ejemplo de salida que dio el autor de la pregunta? En lugar de asumir una cosa u otra y añadir respuesta, deberíamos esperar a que lo verifique el autor y, en todo caso, cerrar como no claro lo que se pregunta

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Consideré que simplemente fue un error de fácil de corregir y que en si el mismo tema "Excluir datos según rango" era lo principal y el error era lo secundario.. 
No sé si me excedí demasiado en mis capacidades.

Comment: Guif if: sería bueno que actualizaras tu pregunta, pues quedó en el limbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `grep` y usando una expresión regular de la siguiente manera.

```
grep -P '(.*\.){3}\K(?![5-9][0-9]$|100)' ips.txt
#     |  |_______| | | |_________|  |____ Busca la expresión "100". ------------------------------------------
#     |      |     | |       |                                                                                |____ Aquí tenemos el rango de numeros (del 50 al 100) sobre el cual
#     |      |     | |       |____  Busca la expresión de dos dígitos, el primero que sea entre 5 y 9         |     excluirá de la búsqueda con
#     |      |     | |              y el segundo entre 0 y 9 (y luego termina, indicado con "$").             |                     | 
#     |      |     | |              Entonces cubres el primer rango entre 50 y 99 el "negative lookahead". ---                      | (esto) 
#     |      |     | |                                                                                                              |
#     |      |     | |____ '?!' Es un "negative lookahead" que busca todo lo que no suceda <----------------------------------------
#     |      |     |       a la expresión regular que sigue.
#     |      |     | 
#     |      |     |____ Lo que encontró anteriormente lo 'olvida' con '\K' y el motor
#     |      |           pretende que empezó desde aquí. "Borrón y cuenta nueva", como decimos en México.
#     |      |
#     |      |____ Atrapa tres veces (señalado con "{3}") el patrón de "<caracteres><punto>", por ejemplo, 111.111.111.
#     |
#     |____ Habilita las expresiones regulares tipo PERL (más avanzadas)
```

O propongo una variante de la respuesta de @sal que es a mi gusto mucho más sencilla.

```
awk -F . '($4<50 || $4>100){print $0}' ips.txt
#      |    |___________|      |__ Imprime todo el renglón ($0 lo indica). <--------
#      |           |                                                               | (entones)
#      |           |                                                               |
#      |           |_______ Si el parametro 4 no está en el intervalo abierto (50,100)
#      |           
#      |____ Usa el punto como delimitador y sobre ese separa.
```

Gracias a una opción dada en los comentarios sé que una versión más simplificada y menos redundante de la segunda opción sería:

```
awk -F . '$4<50 || $4>100' ips.txt
```

Esta última expresión realiza una evaluación y usa el hecho de que `awk` tiene la opción por defecto de imprimir el registro entero (por lo regular un registro es una línea, puesto que el `ORS` es el salto de línea (esto también se puede cambiar)). Esto último curiosamente no lo supe por `gawk(1)` o `awk(1)` sino por [este](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html) apartado y por un [artículo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) en wikipedia.

Comment: `{print $0}` es redundante aquí, `awk '$4<50 || $4>100'` ya hace lo que queremos hacer. En cualquier caso, estás asumiendo cosas que el autor de la pregunta no dejó claras, por lo que sería mejor no responder

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Realmente no lo sabía. Lo probaré en un instante y lo añadiré. ¡Gracias!

Comment: El tema es que {print $0} es la acción predeterminada de Awk cuando se da una condición cierta. Ello permite código mucho más simple. Te recomiendo la lectura de Idiomatic Awk: https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo leeré próximamente. Ya actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: Por cierto, lo de imprimir por defecto la línea entera no es del todo así: imprime por defecto el registro actual, que por defecto es la línea pero puede ser un bloque diferente de caracteres

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' De nuevo gracias, interpreté mal.

Comment: gracias @Cuauhtli me ha funciona